# Change view height in onTouch ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, touch, touch-event, layoutparams

I would like to change view height when user move finger down on screen.

```
    new OnTouchListener() {
        float lastY = Float.MIN_VALUE;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (lastY != Float.MIN_VALUE) {
                    final float dist = event.getRawY() - lastY;

                    myView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = myView.getLayoutParams();
                            lp.height += dist;
                            myView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        }
                    });

                    view.invalidate();
                }
                lastY = event.getRawY();
            }

            if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                lastY = Float.MIN_VALUE;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

But view height changes only when user stops moving finger!

How to change view height immediately when ACTION_MOVE occurred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First*, you don't need to call `invalidate()` or `requestLayout()` because `setLayoutParams()` [already does that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/View.java#View.setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) so calling it manually again will only cause unnecessary overhead.

*Second*, lose the `mView.post()` call: `onTouch()` is executed on the main (aka UI) thread anyway. Just do the layoutparams stuff in the `onTouch()` body along with everything else.

*Third*, your `mView.post()` call is what's probably causing all the trouble because `View.post()` effectively posts the job to UI thread's `Handler`, which queues jobs until the time the UI thread is free to execute them, one by one. And in your case it's too busy running your `onTouch()` method on every event, so everything you post gets executed when you stop delivering touch events - i.e. stop dragging.

*Finally*, here's a good reference on the subject that I used when I had to implement a resizeable view, it's also very likely to cover all the functionality you're trying to implement by hand: [k9mail's own `SplitView` class on GitHub](https://github.com/k9mail/splitview/blob/master/lib/src/com/fsck/splitview/SplitView.java). Note how they just save the coordinates in `ACTION_DOWN` block and then just measure the height from there instead of calling `getHeight()` and incrementing it with last coordinate delta. This allows for one less operation + handling `ACTION_DOWN` and having the mDragging boolean flag will allow you to drop the obscure `lastY = Float.MIN_VALUE;` thing.

Comment: I look at SplitView and make my touch listener like there. Height not increase immediately whatever! May be due that view which I need change height, is anchor for other view in my layout and android must re-layout all view hierarchy?

Comment: @Nik well, that shouldn't be a problem, since `setLayoutParams()` does call `requestLayout()` internally. Hmm. Why don't you update your question and add the new code, the one inspired by SplitView, then we can have a look at what may be the problem there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `view.invalidate()` you could use `view.requestLayout()`.

This wont be super fast though, as it will cause a lot of layout events. It's hard to give more advice without seeing your layout and knowing what kind of effect you are aiming for.

Comment: It not helps! Works like view.invalidate()